# C# ¿Alguien tiene alguna función para validar un string de tipo X.Y.Z (string de versión)?

Tags: c#

Quiero validar si un string tiene el formato X.Y.Z, pero no solo eso, también completar la cadena si viene de la forma "X", "X.", X.Y" o "X.Y." a "X.Y.Z"

Básicamente estoy validando la versión de una app, entonces X, Y y Z solo pueden ser números de un solo dígito.

No doy con una solución sencilla. Mi pregunta es por si es posible validar esto con Regex o algo similar y no tener una función con un montón de if.

Tipo esto:

```
string parameter= "5.";
        bool correctFormat = false;
        string parameterVersion = parameter;
        char[] arrayVersion = parameter.ToCharArray();

        if (arrayVersion != null && !(arrayVersion.Length==0))
        {
            if (arrayVersion.Length == 5) {
                if (!double.IsNaN(Convert.ToDouble(arrayVersion[0]))
                    && !double.IsNaN(Convert.ToDouble(arrayVersion[2]))
                    && !double.IsNaN(Convert.ToDouble(arrayVersion[4]))) //que los 3 caracteres sean numeros, si no, hay algo mal
                    correctFormat = true;
            }//que sea del tamaño X.Y.Z                   
                
                    
            else if (arrayVersion.Length == 4 && arrayVersion[3] == '.')
                parameterVersion += "0";
            else if (arrayVersion.Length == 3 && !double.IsNaN(Convert.ToDouble(arrayVersion[2].ToString())))
                parameterVersion += ".0";
            else if (arrayVersion.Length == 2 && arrayVersion[1] == '.')
                parameterVersion += "0.0";
            else if (arrayVersion.Length == 1 && !double.IsNaN(Convert.ToDouble(arrayVersion[0].ToString())))
                parameterVersion += ".0.0";
        }
        
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Versión incorrecta.");
            correctFormat = false;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Entrada: "+parameter+"\nSalida: "+parameterVersion);
        Console.WriteLine("\nLongitud de la versión de entrada: "+parameterVersion.Length+"\n ¿formato correcto?: "+correctFormat);
```

Comment: X,Y, y Z tienen n digititos ?

Comment: Muestra el código que hayas probado, preguntas sin elaboración se cierran.

Comment: o sea queres validar que es numero.numero.numero... con un split y un par de ifs no sirvio?

Comment: @Yussef X, Y y Z son de un solo dígito

Comment: @gbianchi Sí sirve, pero quiero saber si alguna forma más sencilla

Comment: defini sencilla.. porque lo que hiciste, no solo es sencillo... cubre todas las posibilidades y funciona... o queres refactorizar el codigo???

Comment: @gbianchi Específicamente quisiera saber si es posible hacerlo con Regex o quizá alguna refactorización

Comment: aca no hacemos refactorizaciones (porque son todas totalmente opinables) y seguro que se puede hacer con una regex... que has probado sobre eso? igual, para lo que estas haciendo, usar una regex es matar mosquitos con cañones... tambien se puede hacer con una funcion recursiva... yo sigo viendo que es sencilla.. y capaz todavia se puede simplificar mas... estas cosas podes verlas en el [chat]

Comment: Encontré el objeto de C# para esta tarea es "Version". Con su método compareTo pude lograr la validación. Gracias a todos!

Comment: @Daniel ponlo como respuesta junto con la forma como lo usaste! Vas a recibir votos positivos y puedes aceptar tu propia solución :) (y ayudar a otros con el mismo lío en el futuro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con expresiones regulares seguramente se puede, pero creo que lo más simple es usar un [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split) por "puntos". Esto te entregará un Array de string. En tu caso cada string representa un ámbito de la versión.

Con esto te ahorras preguntar por la posición, porque una versión puede tener 0 a n dígitos, y ahí tu código ya no sirve, por ejemplo `10.` el punto está en la posición `2` y no en la `1` tal como tu evaluas.

Luego ocupas un `for` que comience desde el largo de del Array hasta 3 para rellanar los valores faltamente si se da el caso.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetVersion("234.52.123")); //234.52.123
    Console.WriteLine(GetVersion("2")); //2.0.0
    Console.WriteLine(GetVersion("2.")); //2.0.0
    Console.WriteLine(GetVersion("2.1")); //2.1.0
    Console.WriteLine(GetVersion("2.1.")); //2.1.0
}

public static string GetVersion(string ver)
{
    var versions = ver.Split('.').Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out int r) ? r : 0); //quizas no es necesario transformar a int, si es que tu estas seguro que siempre son números
    for (int i= versions.Count(); i< 3; i++)
    {
        versions.Append(0);
    }
    return string.Join(".", versions);
}
```

Comment: Justo llegué a una solución con expresiones regulares, pero mucho mas engorrosa que esta. Gracias!